# Android back button not working in Cocos2d-x

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I want quit my Cocos2d-x game on back button press in Android. For this I have overloaded the `CCLayer::keyBackClicked` method in my class `GameScene` and I have also called `setKeypadEnabled(true)` from `GameScene::init`. However, the `keyBackClicked` method is never called when pressing the back button, I have checked with a `CCLog` message. What else do I have to do to make this work? I have searched a lot on this topic and found the above solution but it's not working.

Here is my code

```
bool GameScene:: init() {
    if(CCLayer::init()) {
        CCLog("Init");
        this->setKeypadEnabled(true);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void GameScene:: keyBackClicked(void) {
    CCLayer::keyBackClicked();
    CCLOG("cclayer key back clicked");
    exit(0);
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Please show us your code for this. As far as I know, what you described is what you need to do to support the back button.

Comment: here is my codebool GameScene:: init()
{
    if(CCLayer::init())
    {
        CCLog("Init");

        this->setKeypadEnabled(true);
        return true;        
    }
    
    return false;
}

Comment: void GameScene:: keyBackClicked(void)
{
    CCLayer::keyBackClicked();
    
 CCLOG("cclayer key back clicked");
    exit(0);
}

Comment: i have used the node built from cocos builder and added it as a child to GameScene class. is there any prob with this that i am not getting callback for backkey press in  GameScene class??

Comment: What version of Cocos2d-x are you using? Is the GameScene::init called properly so that you see the "Init" message in the log?

Comment: Try to press Shift + F1 on your PC. Does it work?

Comment: [here is some tutorials](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/cocos2d-android/) for cocos2d may be you get some help.

Answer (score 1):

If GameScene extends CCLayer class -

```
void GameScene:: keyBackClicked(void) {
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->end();

    #if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS)
        exit(0);
    #endif
}
```

I think it is important to end the Director first and then exit.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the keypad by calling `this->setKeyPadEnable(true);`

Override onKeyReleased method :

```
void GameScene::onKeyReleased(EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, cocos2d::Event *event)
{
    // Back button pressed
    if (keyCode == EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_BACKSPACE) {
        Director::getInstance()->end();
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CCLayer add the delegate function in the onEnter() function call,you may need call **CCLayer::onEnter** in  **GameScene::onEnter()** or maybe you need add it elsewhere.

```
CCLayer::onEnter
//
...
    if (m_bKeypadEnabled)
    {
        pDirector->getKeypadDispatcher()->addDelegate(this);
    }
//
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void GameScene:: keyBackClicked(void) 
{
    CCLOG("cclayer key back clicked");
    exit(0);
}
```

also enable

```
this->setKeyPadEnable(true);
```

Comment: how  to do this using cocos2d-x 3.2

Answer (score 0):

keyBackClicked is only work if your class (GameScene) inherit from CCLayer otherwise its not working. From your Question i think you inherit your class from CCScene not from CClayer thats why back button key is not working. 
You Can also handle back button in function "KeyDown" from Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView.java.